# GNU Radio / Python - USRP receiving and collecting at the same time

Tags: python, python-2.7, gnuradio, usrp, gnuradio-companion

I apologize in advance for the lengthy question. I want to make sure I have everything down. I've set up a seemingly simple python script with the help of GNU Radio (and using a USRP b200) to continuously receive a signal, and when this signal reaches a certain power level, a threshold variable will let the user know a signal has been detected and then I want to start collecting that signal to view later. So I have a python script that waits for a signal to be detected, then when it is, It will start collecting using another python script. **The problem is, the USRP won't let me receive and collect at the same time. Can USRPs receive and collect simultaneously?**

**My GNU Radio setup**

```
UHD: USRP Source ---> Low Pass Filter ---> Complex to Mag^2 ---> Threshold ---> Probe Signal
```

with a Function probe and a label (to show the user if a signal is being detected)

**GNU generated / my updated Python Code**

```
Class autoCollect(gr.top_block, Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        .
        .    #some setup stuff
        .
        def _probe_variable_probe():
            while True:
                val = self.probe_signal.level()
                try:
                    self.set_probe_variable(val)
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
                if val == 1.0    # If there is a signal detected...
                    p = subprocess.Popen("python USRP_collect.py", shell=True)
                    p.wait()
        _probe_variable_thread = threading.Thread(target=_probe_variable_probe)
        _probe_variable_thread.daemon = True
        _probe_variable_thread.start()
        .
        .    #some more setup stuff
        .

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tb = autoCollect()
    tb.start()
    tb.show()
```

**USRP_Collect**

```
Class usrp_read(...):

    def __init__(...)
    .
    .
    .
if name == '__main__':
    tb = usrp_read(...)
    tb.run()
```

**Problem:**
When I try to call for USRP_collect to run in my autoCollect script, it starts running it but when it gets to `tb = usrp_read()` it gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "USRP_collect.py", line 29, in __init__
```

Then a runtime error

```
empty device address
```

I've tried running a view file instead of the collect file (view only displays an fft of the signal, which works on its own) and it gives me the same error, when I try to call the class.

Answer (score 1):

> Can USRPs receive and collect simultaneously?

Yes, all devices are full-duplex capable.

Your mistake is to try to use the same USRP from two processes. That doesn't work – you need to integrate your receiver and transmitter in the same flow graph / process.

In fact, in GNU Radio this is easy: just use a USRP Sink and Source in one flow graph. I don't know what your flow graph does, but also: signal probes are almost certainly not the way to go.

Comment: Well basically I am trying to receive a signal which I am transmitting using another USRP (working). Then I want to know if the power level of the signal is high enough for me to determine if there is a signal present. I did all that by putting in a threshold and the probe to constantly update and let me know if there is a signal. Any idea how I can keep that working while collecting if the signal is present?